# Have router at home on desktop-- can I access internet with laptop while traveiling

Tags: wireless-router, internet-connection

I have a Linksys router located at home to access laptop in other areas of house.  When I am traveling, is there a way to access the internet through my router at hone?

Comment: Short answer, no.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer: If by "access the Internet through my router at home" you mean, "When I am travelling and I access the Internet somewhere that blocks some content, can I bypass the content blocking by connecting to my home router and then using my (unblocked) home Internet connection to access that content", the answer is: It's possible by tricky.

The easiest way to do so would be to leave a computer on at home that has Remote Desktop configured.  See this link for details on how to [Connect To Another Computer Using Remote Desktop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/connect-using-remote-desktop-connection#connect-using-remote-desktop-connection=windows-7).  When configuring remote desktop, you'll want to open the appropriate ports on your router to allow an external connection to reach your internal machine.  The specifics will vary based on your router and OS version, but here's [a General Remote Desktop Port Configuration Tutorial](https://www.dynu.com/Resources/Tutorials/DynamicDNS/RemoteDesktop).

Last but not least, you'll have to set up some way to find your home router over the Internet.  The easiest way is usually to use a DynamicDNS service. Many routers (such as [ASUS routers](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/asus-ddns/)) have DDNS service built in.  Others need manual configuration using a [Free Dynamic DNS service](https://www.dynu.com/ControlPanel/AddDDNS) or a [Paid Dynamic DNS service](http://dyn.com/dns/).  Once configured, you'll be able to find your home router over the Internet with a custom DNS entry something like, `DawnHomeRouter.noip.com` (the specifics to vary based on availability of the DNS name for the chosen provider.)